# Route not working in angular.js with node/express

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I am getting a 404 and cannot figure out why.  I know my mongoDB server and node server are working because I can query and view my services.  Now I am trying to implement an angular.js frontend on top of the services but I keep getting a 404 when I try to access my "home state".

```
    // Configure the app to use routing.  These $ tags are referencing the angular ui-router import.
app.config([
'$stateProvider', 
'$urlRouterProvider',
function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    // tells your route what controller to use when it gets there
    $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: '/home.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
        resolve: {
            postPromise: ['posts', function(posts){
                return posts.getAll();
            }]
        }
    });

    $stateProvider
    .state('posts', {
        url: '/posts/{id}', 
        templateUrl: '/posts.html',
        controller: 'PostsCtrl'
    });


    // .otherwise means "route to this place if the url is anything else" || like an if/else for url routing
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
}]);
```

This is some code from app.js that is throwing the code.  Standard express generated code here.

```
// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
var err = new Error('Not Found');
err.status = 404;
next(err);
});
```

This is the javscript that should be displaying, which is located in my index.ejs view page in node.

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="/home.html">
  <div class="page-header">
    <h1>Flapper News</h1>
  </div>
  <div ng-repeat="post in posts | orderBy:'-upvotes'">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"
             ng-click="incrementUpvotes(post)"></span>
             {{post.upvotes}}
             <span style="font-size:20px; margin-left:10px;">
                <a ng-show="post.link" href="{{post.link}}">
                    {{post.title}}
                </a>
                <span ng-hide="post.link">
                    {{post.title}}
                </span>
                <span>
                    <a href="#/posts/{{$index}}">Comments</a>
                </span>
        </div>



        <form ng-submit="addPost()"
            style="margin-top:30px;">
            <h3>Add a new post</h3>

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text"
                    class="form-control"
                    placeholder="Title"
                    ng-model="title"></input>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" 
                    class="form-control"
                    placeholder="Link" 
                    ng-model="link"></input>
            </div>
            <button type="submit">Post</button>
        </form>
</script>
```

Also for reference, my imports on the index.ejs page

```
<head>
        <title>Flapper News</title>
            <link    href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


            <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.min.js"></script>
            <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.10/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
            <script src="/javascripts/angularApp.js"></script>
            <style> .glyphicon-thumbs-up { cursor:pointer } </style>
    </head>
```

I am baffled by this 404 because I feel like I have a good understanding of this in-line templating routing set up.  I have tried everything I can think of and nothing will resolve this 404.

```
GET /home 404 19.131 ms - 1246
```

Comment: are you using Html5Mode?  if you are, you need a route in express to handle it; if not, then your angular route is `#/home`, where the `#` suppresses the browser reload and call to the server for a non-existent page.  if you have a Get in your browser for `/home`, you tried to request that from the server, which the server can't respond to.

Comment: I am unsure if I am using Html5Mode, however I do have                                            
 $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');

Comment: does going to `http://yoursite.com/#/home` instead of `http://yoursite.com/home` work?

Comment: I get 404 for /#/home and /home.  However, I can access my services through urls like /posts and /comments.

Comment: you haven't listed those states in your code, so I'm not entirely sure what's different with them.  the code you did post for `.state` looks pretty standard...

Comment: I updated my code to include the entire app.config

Comment: When using node/express with angular you have to define your static pages, etc so you can use the angular routing. Have you done anything like this? Let's see your entire node app.js

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you made the same mistake I did following this tutorial: you deleted the root route in routes/index.js which is need to serve up the initial index.ejs file.  Here it is to add back to your route:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});
```